# tuple_size and an inhereted class from tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, tuples, c++11

I have following code:

```
class TR_AgentInfo : public tuple<
                              long long,         //AgentId
                              string,         //AgentIp
                              >
{
public:
TR_AgentInfo() {}
TR_AgentInfo(
  const long long& AgentId,
  const string& AgentIp,
   )
{
    get<0>(*this) = AgentId;
    get<1>(*this) = AgentIp;
}

long long getAgentId() const { return get<0>(*this); }
void setAgentId(const long long& AgentId) { get<0>(*this) = AgentId; }

string getAgentIp() const { return get<1>(*this); }
void setAgentIp(const string& AgentIp) { get<1>(*this) = AgentIp; }
};
```

Now I want to use this code:

```
int count = tuple_size<TR_AgentInfo>::value;
```

but gcc give this error:

```
error: incomplete type std::tuple_size<TR_AgentInfo> used in nested name specifier
```

now what can I do ?

Comment: What's the actual problem, though? Seems like the tuple size is always 2, so why the gymnastics?

Comment: I simplified my code too much!
these codes will be generated by a TemplateGenerator made by myself, then will be used in another template library that it is very generic.

Comment: Why don't you store the tuple size as a static class constant? Or typedef the tuple so you can later use `std::tuple_size<MyClass::tuple_type>::value`?

Comment: I want to the child class has behavior like a tuple exactly.

Comment: It's hard to proceed without knowing your real code at this point. If your `TR_AgentInfo` is itself a template, then you can just specialize `std::tuple_size` for it.

Comment: Post real code (complete and minimal), then we can talk. No point me guessing into the blue.

Comment: this class is complete. my problem is in another class that it take a template parameter which is tuple.

Comment: If your class is complete, then say `namespace std { template<> struct tuple_size<TR_AgentInfo> { static const size_t value = 2; }; }`. Adding specialisations to the namespace is expressly permitted.

Comment: it works. please post your solution as a separate post, then I will check it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want your one class to work with `std::tuple_size`, you can simply provide a specialization:

```
namespace std
{
  template<> struct tuple_size<TR_AgentInfo>
  {
    static const size_t value = 2;

    // alternatively, `tuple_size<tuple<long long, string>>::value`
    // or even better, `tuple_size<TR_AgentInfo::tuple_type>::value`, #1
  };
}
```

You are expressly allowed to add specializations to the namespace `std`, precisely for situations like yours.

If your actual class is itself templated, you can simply replace `2` by an appropriate construction. For example, for suggestion #1 you could add a typedef for `tuple_type` to your class. There are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of `TR_AgentInfo` kicking around, you can use function template type deduction to make it friendlier, like so:

```
template <typename... T>
std::size_t get_tuple_size(std::tuple<T...> const &)
{
  return sizeof...(T);
}
```

and call

```
TR_AgentInfo info;
int count = get_tuple_size(info);
```

otherwise you need to use proper metaprogramming to get at the base class, but facilities are available.

Comment: I do not want to get it at the base class. I need to use **tuple_size**

Comment: You're asking for the tuple_size of a class which isn't a tuple. The base class is a tuple. You can get the tuple_size of that base class. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I want to get **tuple_size** of the child class.

Comment: What do you think is the difference?  In what sense is the child class here a different tuple from the base class?  After all, you're using public inheritance to explicitly express an IS-A relationship, ie, saying `TR_AgentInfo` **is a** `tuple<long long, string>`.